# Unity, Calling Resources.Load from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I made a prefab to be instantiated in game.

But because I wish it to be instantiated "behind the scene", which means, create all those multiple copies of prefabs "while the player is doing something else".

So I put the code generating the prefab "in another thread".

But the Unity told me that "Load can only be called from the main thread."

I tried to move the code into a coroutine, but unfortunately coroutine runs in the "main thread"!

Or maybe I should say, they don't do multiple coroutines "parallely and concurrently"!

So could somebody please be so kind and teach me what should I do!?

Much appreciated!

**Codes: (In case needed, even though I don't think it would do any good)**

```
void Start()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Do);

    t.Start();
}

private void Do()
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        GameObject RaceGO = (GameObject)(Resources.Load("Race"));

        RaceGO.transform.SetParent(Content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not solution but You can't access the Unity API from any outside thread but the main. As unity only run on Main tread so you have to do each and every thing in main tread like instantiation, Loading Scene, Co-routines Etc, But you can do calculation out side of main tread and then take that information back to main thread do thing what ever you want.

Comment: But there is unity job system that might help in this case. there is a lot of tutorial you check out.Like this one :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gibqhg0wMA0

Comment: You can't. I guess what you are looking for is [`Resources.LoadAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html)

Comment: @derHugo What you're trying to say is "There is no way I can instantiate multiple prefabs simultaneously"!?

Comment: No .. what I says is you can't call `Resources.Load` from a thread or run it on a thread. Most of Unity's API can only be used in the main thread. You should change the title because this is the answer to your title actually ;)

Comment: @derHugo Oh, OK, sorry I misunderstood! So `Resources.LoadAsync` could do the job!?

Comment: Yeah `Async` always is a hint that the code is executed [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async) which usually means on a separate thread. You should checkout Menyus' answer below. You can easily expand the provided code example to load multiple resources at the same time. Just use e.g. `yield return new WaitUntil(() => request1.IsDone && request2.IsDone ...);` instead of the the `while`

Comment: @derHugo Thanks. I'll go research it as best as I could. But how about the job thingy Swati was talking about above!? Will that do a better job!?

Comment: If you get it to run with `LoadAsync` you should be fine already. Honestly I don't know the job system very well but it seems to be quite an implementation overhead to me

Comment: @derHugo OK, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ofcourse you could go through the [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/JobSystem.html) and make your own picture of it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unable to test this code atm, but i guess you get the idea.

```
GameObject raceGameObject;
// Start "Message" can be a coroutine
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Load the resource "Race" asynchronously
    var request = Resources.LoadAsync<GameObject>("Race");
    while(!request.IsDone) {
        yield return request;
    }
    raceGameObject = request.asset;
    Do();
}

private void Do()
{
    // Instantiating 1000 gameobjects is nothing imo, if yes split it then, with a coroutine
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        GameObject RaceGO = Instantaite(raceGameObject);
        RaceGO.transform.SetParent(Content);
    }
}
```

Also i do not recommend this you should just make a `public Gameobject myGameObj;` field assign a value to it inside the editor then just do this:

```
// Assign this inside the editor
public GameObject Race;

void Start()
{
    Do();
}

private void Do()
{
    // Instantiating 1000 gameobjects is nothing imo, if yes split it then, with a coroutine
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        GameObject RaceGO = Instantaite(Race);
        RaceGO.transform.SetParent(Content);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this `while(!request.IsDone) {
        yield return request;
    }` is a bit redundant and you could either directly `yield return Resources.LoadAsync(...);` or just `yield return null;` in the loop

Comment: @derHugo i think you are right, for sure returning request is redundant, will edit the answer tho when i tried the code